# Cursor becomes invisible when Weston.ini set to Kiosk mode

Tags: mouse, gui, wayland, input

I am running a custom crank GUI application on a SBC with an Ubuntu OS. The application is set to auto start on boot and the Weston.ini is setup for kiosk mode.

The graphical application start appropriately but the cursor is not visible. I am still able to perform left click presses with my mouse and interact with the application despite the cursor not being visible.

I am running Weston in kiosk mode as this fixed an issue where the crank application would not accept mouse clicks (known Wayland issue).

One work around I have currently is to feed the crank storyboard engine a software render cursor option. This works perfectly, except the cursor is tiny and this may be impossible to change the size as it is part of the storyboard engine itself.